# Error creating temp dir in hadoop.tmp.dir /tmp/hadoop-sha due to Permission denied

Tags: java, debugging, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I got the following error message when I ran my java map reduce code on the hadoop cluster:

```
-sh-3.2$ hadoop jar PearsonSim1.jar PearsonSim.PearsonDriver1 /user/sha/data/rating_sample_item /user/sha/cf/PearsonSim1
```

"Error creating temp dir in hadoop.tmp.dir /tmp/hadoop-sha due to Permission denied"

Has anyone encountered such problem before? I'm wondering whether there's any issue with my code or simply account permission setup. My code works fine on Cloudera's CDH3 VM.

Could anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

`hadoop.tmp.dir` is used by the job client to assemble your job classes / files etc before sending them up to the job tracker.

For you to get this error message, one of the following is probably true:

You don't have write & execute permissions on the /tmp directory as your current user. Try manually creating a directory in /tmp and see if you get an error message. If you do then you'll need to open up the permissions on that folder (`sudo chmod a+rwx /tmp`)

If that's ok, then does the directory /tmp/hadoop-sha already exist, and do you have permissions to write to that folder?

Comment: Is hadoop.tmp.dir an hdfs path or local path? I just tried to create them in both local and hdfs, and

Comment: local path, on the machine where you're submitting your jobs from

Comment: There are other places that hadoop.tmp.dir is used, are you seeing this error after the job has submitted, or before the job even starts?

Comment: You can also get out of disk space with this directory.